# Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence and that the numbers $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}...$ are limit points. Show that $0$ is also a limit point.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence and that the numbers $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}...$ are limit points. Show that $0$ is also a limit point.

I don't really have any clue where to start. Is the proof somewhat inductive, by using the epsilon definition of a limit, showing it works for $\frac{1}{2}$, followed by $\frac{1}{3}$ and so on.

Comment: No.  Suppose, in contradiction, that $0$ is not a limit point.  Then there must be neighborhood around $0$ such that...what?  And can that be the case?

Comment: @BrianTung so supposing $0$ is not a limit point, this would imply that there are no elements of the sequence $x_n$ which are "near" $0$, which is false since we have $\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$ as a limit point? Would this be good or formal enough to be a proof? I feel like I would still need to use the $\varepsilon$ definition to explicitly show that it is in fact a limit point

Comment: Sure, set $\varepsilon > 0$.  Since it is not zero, $1/\varepsilon$ exists, and there is an integer greater than it.  The conclusion follows.

Comment: how would I sort of formalize the intuition argument regarding there being no elements of the sequence "near" $0$?

Comment: my intuition would be to say. Supposing 0 is not a limit point of $x_n$, this implies $\exists \varepsilon > 0$ and $\exists N$ s.t. $\nexists n>N$ s.t. $| x_n-0 | < \varepsilon$. I'm struggling to find a way to contradict this claim.